# Is there a way to specify "type of current class" in a C# method signature?

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns, types

I'm trying to define an abstract class which other classes will extend, and they have to be able to serialize themselves to JSON and deserialize from JSON.  I want to write the abstract class something like this:

```
public abstract class BaseApiModel {
    public abstract string ToJson();
    public abstract T FromJson(string json);
}
```

... where `T` is the type of the current class.  I would then write an extending class like this:

```
public class ContactApiModel : BaseApiModel {
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    [...other properties...]

    public override string ToJson() {
        [...return serialized JSON string...]
    }

    public override ContactApiModel FromJson(string json) {
        [...return deserialized object...]
    }
}
```

Of course this doesn't work because `T` in the abstract class isn't defined.  But is there some way I can write "this method has to return the type of the current class" in C#?  Do I just going to have to make it return `object`?  Or am I approaching this wrong and there's a better way to structure it?

Comment: Why do that? You are hard-coding the serializer/mapping into a class that shouldn't know anything about it

Comment: You can add a type parameter to BaseApiModel. Call it `TThis` and pass it in when deriving classes. C# does not have a polymorphic `this` type like Typescript for example

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos So where would you suggest putting the `ToJson` and `FromJson` methods?

Comment: In the code that actually needs to generate JSON, eg the controller actions. Perhaps not even there - ASP.NET Web API for example takes care of (de)serialization itself. The API DTOs shouldn't need any specific processing to be serialized.If they do, they aren't API DTOs. Perhaps you should be looking at ways to map the models to DTOs?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos These aren't simply DTO classes, they are doing more than just storing data.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos is correct as this architecture breaks SOLID principles. You could use either extension class with extension methods that extend `BaseApiModel` or create a custom converter class that will be solely responsible for converting the `BaseApiModel` to/from json

Comment: @Jez that's the problem. They *shouldn't* be doing many things at once. As [the saying goes](https://codeopinion.com/web-api-resource-model-isnt-data-model/), `your data model is not your object model is not your resource model is not your message model`.

Comment: So what's the fundamental risk of the `ToJson` and `FromJson` methods?  What's the reasoning behind the principle of not having the class know about its own (de)serialization?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can declare your base class using generics, and in your `ContactApiModel` class just set the `T` parameter to be `ContactApiModel`, as the following:

```
public abstract class BaseApiModel<T> {
    ...
    public abstract T FromJson(string json);
}


public class ContactApiModel : BaseApiModel<ContactApiModel> {
    ...
    public override ContactApiModel FromJson(string json) {
        [...return deserialized object...]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*For future visitors of this:*

A smarter solution would be to not implement that method at all in the corresponding classes and instead use extension methods:

```
public static class ExtendBaseApiModel
{
    public static string ToJson(this T obj) { /* ... */ }
    public static T FromJson<T>(this T obj, string json) where T : BaseApiModel { /* ... */ }
}
```

this will allow you to keep your classes nice and clean + free from serialization hazzle.

still .. there are some words to say

### How to *de*-serialize proper

Assuming this is done to provide custom serialization inside the `ToJson` method and custom deserialization inside the `FromJson` method, then you should not use your own weirdo methods but rather let the framework do it for you.

For *Json.NET*, this should be done by utilizing the `JsonConverter` attribute onto the class and implementing a corresponding [JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) somewhere

### Fun Fact

Combining the extension methods variant with the upper mentioned JsonConverter, you will be able to just serialize about every object by just calling `myobjvar.ToJson(...)`